# Excel chart smoothing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, excel, charts, smoothing, vba

I need to smooth my "chart builder" programmically in javascript. Excel variant of doing it is pretty good but I have no suggestion of what algorithm used. I try to get VBA code of doing it by writing macros but all I have got is (expected) `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Smooth = True`

Is anybody know what algorithm does Microsoft Excel use to smooth chart or the way of looking its code?

[image]

**UPD:** for those who find this question and have the same problem i can recommend this [SVG solution](http://www.particleincell.com/blog/2012/bezier-splines/) with javascript source code

Comment: Google Spreadsheet variant of chart smoothing is acceptable too.

Comment: Polynomial fit of some kind.  See this [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) for examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Splines** are used to do this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

I'm not sure if Excel uses exactly this but *cubic splines* are often used for this kind of 'join the dots' problem. Essentially you fit a set of cubic polynomials (i.e. a set of cubic equations) through the points. Each cubic is used for one or two regions bounded by two or three points. The cubics are defined by preserving not only the value but the *gradient* at each point where one cubic finishes and the next one starts. Quite often the second derivative is set to zero which gives you another boundary condition and better smoothness.

Comment: Yes, it is cubic spline. I find this information and was going to remove question. Anyway, thank you for helpful answer.

Comment: @Glen Swift; also worth mentioning (1) that www.nr.com contains java (not javascript) implementation of cubic spline, and that (2) you ought to switch to a monotone cubic spline scheme for things like cumulative density functions.

Comment: Excel smoothing algorithm uses Catmull-Rom splines: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/how-does-excel-plot-smooth-curves/c751e8ff-9f99-4ac7-a74a-fba41ac80300. Also see here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/649288-extract-excel-scatter-plot-connected-smooth-lines-points-2.html)

Comment: @lori_m: that's helpful and will form my lunchtime reading. In the meantime, do you know if Catmull-Rom splines are continuous to the second order?

Comment: They are C¹ continuous i.e. continuous in first but not second derivative